# JW Player open video in popup configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jwplayer

how to configure for popup for video in JWPlayer

```
 jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                    flashplayer: "player.swf",
                    file: 'http://youtu.be/wi8N0pwiEuzc',
                    width: '280',
                    height: '150',
                    image: "Content/images/thumb.jpg",
                    popup:'true'

                });
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean a lightbox?

Comment: i need functionality with jwplayer. When i click on play, video will be played in popup.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean a lightbox? Do you have an example of what you mean?